# How to extract links/text from lines containing a specified string?

Tags: text, hyperlink, extract

I have a big .htm file (106 MB). File contains many links (99% of content).

I need to get only those, which contain in url a specified string, phrase.

What is easy way to do it?  That can by extracting links in html format or also in text format.

Comment: maybe by using grep?

Comment: grep for windows can do this?

Comment: ok. I have done it with grep for windows. Thanks.